# How do I round a float to a specified number of significant digits in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, floating-point, significant-digits

It would be nice to have an equivalent of [R's signif](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/base/html/Round.html) function in Ruby.

For example:

```
>> (11.11).signif(1)
10
>> (22.22).signif(2)
22
>> (3.333).signif(2)
3.3
>> (4.4).signif(3)
4.4 # It's usually 4.40 but that's OK. R does not print the trailing 0's
    # because it returns the float data type. For Ruby we want the same.
>> (5.55).signif(2)
5.6
```

Comment: Would this question be suitable for http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 16):

There is probably better way, but this seems to work fine:

```
class Float
  def signif(signs)
    Float("%.#{signs}g" % self)
  end
end

(1.123).signif(2)                    # => 1.1
(11.23).signif(2)                    # => 11.0
(11.23).signif(1)                    # => 10.0
```

Comment: Brilliant! It's the "g" specifier of printf (a.k.a sprintf, a.k.a %) and then cast to float! Brilliant!

Comment: This implementation should be build-in to Ruby. Does anyone care to submit a patch?

Comment: Wait. A nuance: (5.55).signif(2) # should be => 5.6 but gives 5.5

Comment: I'm more than half way to a good pull request to ruby 1.9 (https://github.com/alevchuk/ruby/commit/bc2253)! But need to take care of (5.55).signif(2) # => 5.6

Comment: I'm thinking of adopting/integrating this code from R, http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/nmath/fprec.c into Ruby's numeric.c

Answer (score 8):

Here's an implementation that doesn't use strings or other libraries.

```
class Float
  def signif(digits)
    return 0 if self.zero?
    self.round(-(Math.log10(self).ceil - digits))
  end
end
```

Comment: This does the underlying maths with the built-in library. I'd say this is the 'right' way.

nb you can simplify the line that does the work:
`self.round(digits - Math.log10(self).ceil)`

Answer (score 3):

I don't see anything like that in Float. Float is mostly a wrapper for the native `double` type and given the usual binary/decimal issues, I'm not that surprised that Float doesn't allow you to manipulate the significant digits.

However, [BigDecimal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) in the standard library does understand significant digits but again, I don't see anything that allows you to directly alter the significant digits in a BigDecimal: you can ask for it but you can't change it. But, you can kludge around that by using a no-op version of the `mult` or `add` methods:

```
require 'bigdecimal'
a = BigDecimal.new('11.2384')
a.mult(1, 2) # the result is 0.11E2   (i.e. 11)
a.add(0, 4)  # the result is 0.1124E2 (i.e. 11.24)
```

The second argument to these methods:

> If specified and less than the number of significant digits of the result, the result is rounded to that number of digits, according to `BigDecimal.mode`.

Using BigDecimal will be slower but it might be your only choice if you need fine grained control or if you need to avoid the usual floating point problems.

Comment: [`BigDecimal#new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-c-new) takes a second parameter that limits the number of significant digits for the number.

Comment: @jwadsack: But that only works when creating a new BigDecimal, you can't change the `digits` value of an existing BigDecimal. I think that's what I meant by "I don't see anything that allows you to directly alter the significant digits in a BigDecimal".

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for Ruby's [Decimal](http://ruby-decimal.rubyforge.org/).

You could then write:

```
require 'decimal/shortcut'
num = 1.23541764
D.context.precision = 2
num_with_2_significant_digits = +D(num.to_s) #  => Decimal('1.2')
num_with_2_significant_digits.to_f #  => 1.2000000000000002
```

Or if you prefer to use the same syntax add this as a function to class Float like this:

```
class Float
  def signif num_digits
    require 'decimal/shortcut'
    D.context.precision = num_digits
    (+D(self.to_s)).to_f
  end
end
```

Usage would then be the same, i.e.

```
 (1.23333).signif 3
 # => 1.23
```

To use it, install the gem

```
gem install ruby-decimal
```

Answer (score 3):

Some of the previous answers and comments have alluded to this solution but this is what worked for me:

```
# takes in a float value and returns another float value rounded to 
# given significant figures.    
def round_to_sig_figs(val, sig_figs)
  BigDecimal.new(val, sig_figs).to_f
end
```

Answer (score 0):

@Blou91's answer is nearly there, but it returns a string, instead of a float. This below works for me:

```
(sprintf "%.2f", 1.23456).to_f
```

So as a function,

```
def round(val, sig_figs)
  (sprintf "%.#{sig_figs}f", val).to_f
end
```

Comment: This rounds to the specific number of decimal places, but what's wanted is to round to a specific number of significant digits.

Answer (score -2):

Use sprintf if you want to print trailing zeros

```
2.0.0-p353 :001 > sprintf "%.3f", 500
 => "500.000"
2.0.0-p353 :002 > sprintf "%.4f", 500
 => "500.0000"
2.0.0-p353 :003 >
```